# Github CLI or API, can I see which commit a Github Action workflow was run on?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api, github-cli

Using Github's CLI tool, I can see a Github Action workflow's log by

```
gh run view [ID] --log
```

Submitting the ID of a run, this returns the run's log. Now, if I don't have the ID, is there any way to find out from a commit SHA, if there are any GH Action runs associated with it (as in: They were run from a branch whose tip was that commit) and retrieve their IDs remotely, through Github's API or CLI?